# Extending Excel UI Visual Studio 2015

Tags: excel, vsto, ribbon

I'm creating a VSTO Add-in for Microsoft Excel. I created a custom tab via Ribbon UI designer. But I does not show up when I launch Excel. Add-in is loaded, as I see it in COM-objects on DEVELOPER tab.

There are a lot of step-by-step tutorials, but following them does not help me.

How should I make my custom tab visible in Excel Workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO provides two main ways for customizing the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI):

- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using the Ribbon Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386104.aspx)

Do you get any UI errors in Excel? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

Comment: You saved my day! I turned on UI errors in Excel and figured out what was wrong. Thanks!